# How to find the first four terms of the maclaurin series of $f(x) = e^{e^x}$

Tags: calculus

I tried substituting the maclaurin series for $e^x$ into the equation, but that doesn’t seem to give the right answer.

I’m not sure what do besides just taking the derivatives.

Comment: What was the wrong answer you got?  What was the method you used?  Yes, this can be done taking derivatives, and (more difficult) it can be done by substituting series.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We know
$$
e^x = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\dots
$$
so then
$$\begin{align}
\exp(e^x) &= \exp\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\dots\right)
\\ &= e^1 e^x e^{x^2/2} e^{x^3/6}\dots
\\
&= e \left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\dots\right)
\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{8}+\dots\right)
\left(1+\frac{x^3}{6}+\dots\right)\cdots
\\ &=
e\left(1+x+x^2+\frac{5}{6} x^3 + \dots\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: I like the way you manipulate exponential(s).

Answer (score 1):

By Taylor with the substitution $x\leftrightarrow e^x$,

$$e^{e^x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(e^{x})^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{nx}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^\infty \dfrac{(nx)^m}{m!}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty\dfrac{n^mx^m}{n!m!}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{n^m}{n!}\right)\frac{x^m}{m!}.$$

Then we can evaluate the inner sums as follows:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{n^0}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac1{n!}=e,$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{n^1}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac1{(n-1)!}=e,$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{n^2}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{n-1+1}{(n-1)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac1{(n-2)!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac1{(n-1)!}=2e,$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{n^3}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(n-2)(n-1)+3(n-1)+1}{(n-1)!}
\\=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac1{(n-3)!}+3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac1{(n-2)!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac1{(n-1)!}=5e.$$

Note that the coefficients so computed are the Bell numbers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number and

$$e^{e^x}=e\sum_{m=0}^\infty B_m\frac{x^m}{m!}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=e^x-1$. Consider the first $4$ terms of the MacLaurin series of $f$:$$x+\frac12x^2+\frac16x^3.\tag1$$Now replace each $x$ in $(1)$ by $(1)$ itself:$$x+\frac12x^2+\frac16x^3+\frac12\left(x+\frac12x^2+\frac16x^3\right)^2+\frac16\left(x+\frac12x^2+\frac16x^3\right)^3.\tag2$$Now, in $(2)$ take only those terms whose degree is smaller than $4$:$$x+x^2+\frac56x^3.$$These are the first terms of the MacLaurin series of $f$. So, since\begin{align}e^{e^x}&=e\times e^{-1+e^x}\\&=e\times e^{f(x)}\\&=e\times f\bigl(f(x)\bigr)+e,\end{align}we have that the first terms of the MacLaurin series of $e^{e^x}$ are$$e+ex+ex^2+\frac56ex^3.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$f(x)=e^{e^x}\\f'(x)=f(x)e^x\\f''(x)=(f'(x)+f(x))e^x=f(x)(e^x+e^{2x})\\f'''(x)=(f(x)+2f'(x)+f''(x))e^x=f(x)(e^x+3e^{2x}+e^{3x})$